# cmd for deleting files when name is not in a list but only when their folder doesn't have a string in its name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I don't know much about cmd, but I have a folder X with a lot of subfolders and I need to create a cmd for deleting all the files in those subfolders but only:
- when file name is not in a like (`list.txt` -I've placed it in  folder `X`, but I can move it)
AND
- the folder that contains that file DOESN'T have a string (`2019`) in its name.

In the file `list.txt` I have all the folder's path of the files (so something like `X/folder1/folder2/filename.jpg`).
The files to be deleted are not only `.jpg`.

Looking around I've tried:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions
set "folder=C:\X"
set "excludeFile=C:\X\list.txt"

for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%folder%" ^| findstr /vibg:"%excludeFile%"') do del "%folder%\%%F"
)
```

but it doesn't work (and I don't know how to say to exclude folders with `2019` in their name).
Anyone can help?

This is what's in `list.txt`:

```
1.pdf
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.pdf
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a sample of `list.txt`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the folder names exactly like you do for the files, namely using [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), or [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html).

Furthermore, I recommend to change to the currently processed directory for each loop iteration (using [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)/[`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)), because [`dir /B`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) only returns pure file names, so you could easily work in the wrong folder.

This is how I would code it:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Define constants here:
set "folder=C:\X"
set "excludeFile=C:\X\list.txt"
set "excludeName=2019"
rem // Change to the root directory:
pushd "%folder%" && (
    rem // Loop through all directories but exclude those with certain partial names:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D "*" ^| find /V /I "%excludeName%"') do (
        rem // Change into currently iterated directory:
        pushd "%%D" && (
            rem // Loop through all files but exclude those listed in the list file:
            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
                dir /B /A:-D "*.*" ^| findstr /V /L /I /X /G:"%excludeFile%"
            ') do (
                rem // Actually delete a file (remove `/P` after testing!):
                del /P "%%F"
            )
            rem // Return from currently iterated directory to root directory:
            popd
        )
    )
    rem // Return to original working directory:
    popd
)
endlocal
```

You may have noticed the changed options of `findstr`: I added `/L` to force literal searches; then I replaced `/B` by `/X` to match the whole file names (not just the beginning).

You may want to remove the `/P` (confirmation prompt for every file) option from [`del`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) and to add the `/F` (force deleting read-only files) and the `/A` option (to delete hidden files too).

---

The main problem in your code is that you are never using the [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variable `%%a`; in the inner loop you need to replace every occurrence of `%folder%` by `%%~a`.

Comment: Thanks!

It seems there's a problem when checking if file name is in the %excludeFile% or not.

I've tried with this 
X\folder1\1.pdf
X\folder2\2.jpg

in the file list.txt
but the file 3.jpg that is in X\folder2 is not deleted.

I've tried also leaving only files name in the list.txt, so
1.pdf
2.jpg

but nothing changes.

I've added an echo after
                dir /B /A:-D "%%D\*.*" ^| findstr /V /L /I /X /G:"%excludeFile%"
            ') do (

but it's never displaying it

Should I write those file names in the list in a different way?

Comment: You cannot put full paths into the exclusion file, it only works when pure file names are listed, because `dir /B ...` returns pure file names only, which are then filtered by `findstr`...

Comment: Thanks!
I've tried also with
1.pdf
2.jpg (each name on a newline)
in the list.txt, but nothing changes (and I still don't get that echo displayed)...

Comment: In the output I have:

The system cannot find the file specified.
FINDSTR: Cannot read strings from C:\X\list.txt

Comment: Ok, the error
FINDSTR: Cannot read strings from C:\X\list.txt
was my fault (wrong path), but now I still get the error
The system cannot find the file specified.

and I still don't see desplayed the echo I put after

            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
                dir /B /A:-D "%%D\*.*" ^| findstr /V /L /I /X /G:"%excludeFile%"
            ') do (

Comment: What is the exact value of `%excludeFile%`?

Comment: It's a txt file containing this list:  
  
1.pdf
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.pdf

Comment: with one file name per row (I've added two spaces at the end here, but I don't know why it's coming in the same row..)

Comment: That is just perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry to be back here, but now I do have to check the full path of the file.
I mean, in the list.txt I'll have full path and name file and I have to delete files only if they are not in that list and not in a folder with 2019 in it...So if I have one file file1.jpg in folders C:\X\Y\A, in C:\X\Y\B_2019 and C:\X\Y\D and in the list.txt I have C:\X\Y\D\file1.jpg, I have to delete file1.jpg from C:\X\Y\A

Comment: You were saying that dir /B returns pure file names only.
I've tried using dir /B /S but I'm experiencing something strange.
If I have "folder=C:\X",, that file is deleted also from C:\X\Y\B_2019, while if I have C:\X\Y\ the file is correctly deleted only from C:\X\Y\A.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks again!

Comment: I guess that if I use
`for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
                dir /B /S /A:-D "*.*" ^| findstr /V /L /I /X /G:"%excludeFile%"`

I can avoid the part
`for /F "delims= eol=|" %%D in ('dir /ad/s/b "*" ^| find /V /I "%excludeName%"') do (`

but then I don't know how to check if the last directory contains `%excludeName%`...
I've seen that `%%~pF` shows only the path without filename, but I need to check the last folder only...

Comment: Let me suggest that you ask a new question concerning that issue (referencing this one)...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set "folder=C:\X"
set "excludeFile=C:\X\list.txt"

for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    for %%b in ("%%a\*") do (
        findstr /lx "%%~nxb" "%excludefile%" >nul || ECHO del "%%b"
    )
)
```

The `for /d %%a` loop processes each folder (depth=1, not recursive).
The `for %%b` processes each file (`%%a\*`) in that folder.
`findstr` looks if the filename and extension (`%%~nxb`) is in the exclude file (`/l` = literal, `/x` = "whole line" and if not (`||`), the file is deleted.

NOTE: Remove the `ECHO` to actually enable the `del` command after troubleshooting (when you are sure, it does exactly what you want)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with a PowerShell script. This runs on the current PowerShell 5+. It can be done with older PowerShell versions with changes. Change the $BaseDir value to your 'X' directory.

When you are satisfied that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

=== Remove-CustomFiles.ps1

```
$BaseDir = "C:\src\t"
$ExcludeDirs = @('*2019*')    # add directory names to exclude here
$PreciousNamesFile = Join-Path -Path $BaseDir -ChildPath 'list.txt'
$PreciousNames = Get-Content -Path $PreciousNamesFile

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $BaseDir -Exclude $ExcludeDirs |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                if ($PreciousNames -notcontains $_.Name) {
                    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
                }
            }
    }
```

Call it at the command line or in a .bat file script using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "Remove-CustomFiles.ps1"
```

Comment: Thanks!
Unfortunately it's not working (files are not deleted) and I don't even know how to debug it, as I've never used PowerShell...
I've tried with this
X\folder1\1.pdf
X\folder2\2.jpg

in the file list.txt but the file 3.jpg that is in X\folder2 is not deleted.

I've tried also leaving only files name in the list.txt, so
1.pdf
2.jpg
but nothing changes...

Comment: Does it produce a message about deleting a file? No files wil be deleted until the `-WhatIf` is removed from the `Remove-Item` command.

Comment: Ok, got it.
I've removed -Whatif and then all the files are deleted.
The problem is that also the file who's name was in the list.txt has been deleted...

Comment: That is what the `-WhatIf` was for. Did the file name appear in the output before you removed `-WhatIf`?

Comment: Yes, in the output I have

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\X\folder2\2.jpg".

Comment: Was`2.jpg` in the `list.txt` file? If so, then the `-WhatIf` showed that the correct files were not saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b /s *.zip ^| findstr /v "[\\][^\\]*ms[^\\]*$"` ) do (
  del /s /q "%%i"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.